# How to correct bug in svg.path library?

Tags: tikz-pgf, svg

The `svg` command from `svg.path` library can display an svg `<path>` in TikZ. But in one particular situation the coordinate calculation fails.

This happens when part of the path is closed by `z` (or `Z`) and the following path instruction is relative (small character like `l`, `c`, ...). Then tikz is supposed to calculate the next coordinate relative to the point moved by `z` (so the beginning of the previous portion of the path), but it acts like if `z` doesn't exists.

Here is an example. The first two paths are supposed to be equivalent to the second ones. This is the case for the blue ones (without `z`) but not for the red ones (with `z` inside).

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{svg.path}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=-1]
    \begin{scope} % absolute paths
      \draw[blue] svg{M0,0 L 10,10   L 10,20};
      \draw[red]  svg{M0,0 L 10,10 Z L  0,10};
    \end{scope}

    \begin{scope}[xshift=20pt] % "equivalent" relative paths
      \draw[blue] svg{M0,0 l 10,10   l 0,10};
      \draw[red]  svg{M0,0 l 10,10 z l 0,10}; % tikz put the last point at (10,20)
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

We can see that the equivalent `SVG` has no problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" viewBox="-10 -10 50 40" width="500" height="400">
  <g fill="none" stroke-width=".4">
    <path stroke="blue" d="M0,0 L 10,10   L 10,20"/>
    <path stroke="red"  d="M0,0 L 10,10 Z L  0,10"/>
  </g>
  <g fill="none" stroke-width=".4" transform="translate(20)">
    <path stroke="blue" d="M0,0 l 10,10   l 0,10"/>
    <path stroke="red"  d="M0,0 l 10,10 z l 0,10"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

[image]

**Question:** How can we fix `svg.path` library ?

**Note:** I'm also surprised that paths like `(20,0) -- cycle -- ++(0,10)` and `(20,0) -- ++(0,10)` are not equivalent in TikZ (they do not produce the same result inside `\draw[xshift=10] ...;` for example) ... [why](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/283000) ?

Comment: How are the two paths you mention in your note different exactly?

Comment: @cfr The two red paths are supposed to be the same, one written in absolute coordinates and the other in relative ones (the équivalent of `++(...)`). The same for the blue ones. The second blue and the second red have only one `z` (the equivalent of `-- cycle`) as difference, and we can see that the relative coordinates after `z` are not "moved" (but they should be).

Comment: I was asking about the non-equivalence claim in the note. How do `(20,0) -- cycle -- ++(0,10)` and `(20,0) -- ++(0,10)` differ?

Comment: @cfr in the sens that this two paths have no named coordinates and they look the same, normally if you transform them (for example by `[xshift=1cm]`) they should stay the same, but ... look at [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/283000)

Comment: But the paths you mentioned here *do* look the same. I know the paths there do not. Are you saying they are not equivalent in the sense that if you add a named node in, they will differ? But that is hardly obvious from what you say in your note here!

Comment: @cfr `\draw[xshift=1cm] (20,0) -- cycle -- ++(0,10);` and `\draw[xshift=1cm] (20,0) -- ++(0,10);` should look the same, but they don't (one is sloped the other is vertical) !

Comment: I'm not disagreeing. I'm just saying that the paths stated in your question are not not equivalent in the sense that *those* paths produce the same result. So the non-equivalence claim needs explanation.

Comment: @cfr done. Feel free to edit the question if it is not clear ;)

Comment: I am very sorry but... what does the blue part do in illustrating your problem?

Comment: @Symbol1 The "relative" blue path is the same as the relatif red one, except the 'z'. So we can see that 'z' is not moving the last point. And the "absolute" blue one is just here to show to what it should be (and is) equivalent. In short it is here to demonstrate that there is no problem without 'z'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The letter `z`/`Z` in SVG, the `--cycle` in Ti*k*Z, the `\closepath` in PGF, and the letter `h` in PDF close the current subpath. For Ti*k*Z and PGF, they need not remember the initial point of the current subpath since the PDF renderer will do the job.<sup>§¶</sup> For SVG, it is the web browser that does the job.

So the embarrassing thing comes up: For SVG engine over PFG, the reference point of relative commands (those in lower case) is held by `\pgf@lib@svg@last@x` and `\pgf@lib@svg@last@y`. They are updated by all commands but `z`/`Z` because PGF does not know what they are supposed to  be -- they should represent the initial point of the current subpath but PGF just does not remember it.

So we have to allocate two registers that help PGF remember it.

```
\newdimen\pgf@lib@svg@lastmoveto@x
\newdimen\pgf@lib@svg@lastmoveto@y
```

and then update them whenever we meet `m`/`M`
(codes are copy from `pgflibrarysvg.path.code.tex` except those with `% NEW LINE`.)

```
\def\pgf@lib@svg@moveto{%
  \pgf@lib@svg@clear@bezier@quad%
  \pgf@lib@svg@last@x=\pgf@lib@svg@get@num{0}pt%
  \pgf@lib@svg@last@y=\pgf@lib@svg@get@num{1}pt%
  \pgf@lib@svg@lastmoveto@x=\pgf@lib@svg@last@x% NEW LINE
  \pgf@lib@svg@lastmoveto@y=\pgf@lib@svg@last@y% NEW LINE
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@lib@svg@last@x}{\pgf@lib@svg@last@y}}%
  \pgf@lib@svg@read@nums{2}{\pgf@lib@svg@lineto}
}
\def\pgf@lib@svg@moveto@rel{%
  \pgf@lib@svg@clear@bezier@quad%
  \advance\pgf@lib@svg@last@x by\pgf@lib@svg@get@num{0}pt%
  \advance\pgf@lib@svg@last@y by\pgf@lib@svg@get@num{1}pt%
  \pgf@lib@svg@lastmoveto@x=\pgf@lib@svg@last@x% NEW LINE
  \pgf@lib@svg@lastmoveto@y=\pgf@lib@svg@last@y% NEW LINE
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@lib@svg@last@x}{\pgf@lib@svg@last@y}}%
  \pgf@lib@svg@read@nums{2}{\pgf@lib@svg@lineto@rel}
}
```

Now we know how to update `\pgf@lib@svg@last@x` and `\pgf@lib@svg@last@y`

```
\def\pgf@lib@svg@closepath{
  \pgf@lib@svg@finish@prev
  \pgf@lib@svg@last@x=\pgf@lib@svg@lastmoveto@x% NEW LINE
  \pgf@lib@svg@last@y=\pgf@lib@svg@lastmoveto@y% NEW LINE
  \pgfpathclose
  \let\pgf@lib@svg@finish@prev=\relax
  \pgf@lib@svg@clear@bezier@quad%
  \pgfparserswitch{initial}%
}
```

## complete code

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{svg.path}

\makeatletter

\newdimen\pgf@lib@svg@lastmoveto@x
\newdimen\pgf@lib@svg@lastmoveto@y

\def\pgf@lib@svg@moveto{%
  \pgf@lib@svg@clear@bezier@quad%
  \pgf@lib@svg@last@x=\pgf@lib@svg@get@num{0}pt%
  \pgf@lib@svg@last@y=\pgf@lib@svg@get@num{1}pt%
  \pgf@lib@svg@lastmoveto@x=\pgf@lib@svg@last@x% NEW LINE
  \pgf@lib@svg@lastmoveto@y=\pgf@lib@svg@last@y% NEW LINE
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@lib@svg@last@x}{\pgf@lib@svg@last@y}}%
  \pgf@lib@svg@read@nums{2}{\pgf@lib@svg@lineto}
}
\def\pgf@lib@svg@moveto@rel{%
  \pgf@lib@svg@clear@bezier@quad%
  \advance\pgf@lib@svg@last@x by\pgf@lib@svg@get@num{0}pt%
  \advance\pgf@lib@svg@last@y by\pgf@lib@svg@get@num{1}pt%
  \pgf@lib@svg@lastmoveto@x=\pgf@lib@svg@last@x% NEW LINE
  \pgf@lib@svg@lastmoveto@y=\pgf@lib@svg@last@y% NEW LINE
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@lib@svg@last@x}{\pgf@lib@svg@last@y}}%
  \pgf@lib@svg@read@nums{2}{\pgf@lib@svg@lineto@rel}
}

\def\pgf@lib@svg@closepath{
  \pgf@lib@svg@finish@prev
  \pgf@lib@svg@last@x=\pgf@lib@svg@lastmoveto@x% NEW LINE
  \pgf@lib@svg@last@y=\pgf@lib@svg@lastmoveto@y% NEW LINE
  \pgfpathclose
  \let\pgf@lib@svg@finish@prev=\relax
  \pgf@lib@svg@clear@bezier@quad%
  \pgfparserswitch{initial}%
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=-1]
    \begin{scope} % absolute paths
      \draw svg{M0,0 L 10,10 Z L 0,10};
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[xshift=20pt] % "equivalent" relative paths
      \draw svg{M0,0 l 10,10 z l 0,10}; % tikz put the last point at (10,20)
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

---

§ PGF actually remembers something: in `pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex` we see

> ```
> \def\pgfsyssoftpath@closepath{%
>   \expandafter\pgfsyssoftpath@addtocurrentpath\expandafter{\expandafter\pgfsyssoftpath@closepathtoken\pgfsyssoftpath@lastmoveto}%
> }
> ```

Where `\pgfsyssoftpath@lastmoveto` is something like `{10pt}{10pt}` that represents the initial point. This macro is essential for decorations and shapes. But this is pretty low level.

¶ Ti*k*Z actually remembers something: in `tikz.code.tex` we see

> ```
> \def\tikz@@close cycle{%
>   \tikz@flush@moveto%
>   \edef\tikz@timer@start{\noexpand\pgfqpoint{\the\tikz@lastx}{\the\tikz@lasty}}
>   \tikz@make@last@position{\expandafter\pgfpoint\pgfsyssoftpath@lastmoveto}%
>   \tikz@path@close{\expandafter\pgfpoint\pgfsyssoftpath@lastmoveto}%
>   \def\pgfstrokehook{}%
>   \edef\tikz@timer@end{\noexpand\pgfqpoint{\the\tikz@lastx}{\the\tikz@lasty}}%
>   \let\tikz@timer=\tikz@timer@line%
>   \let\tikz@tangent\tikz@timer@start%
>   \tikz@scan@next@command%
> }
> ```

Where `\tikz@make@last@position` retrieve the coordinate in `\pgfsyssoftpath@lastmoveto` and store it in `\tikz@lastxsaved` and `\tikz@lastysaved`. Therefore the Ti*k*Z variant

```
\tikz\draw(0,0)--(1,1)--cycle--++(1,0);
```

behaves well.

Comment: This is very interesting. Thanks ! Just one remark : `cycle` behaves better than 'z' but not well as you can see in [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/283000).

Comment: @Kpym I am not surprised... the `cycle` family is too complex. They are not going to... uh... be good forever.

Comment: The only question is : are you sure that PGF do not remember already in some register the last move ? Is `(current subpath start)` available only on tikz level ?

Comment: I think all this problems are related and a common fix should be made. PGF has to have a `(current subpath start)` equivalent, that can be used by `(current subpath start)`, `z` and `cycle` ;)

Comment: @Kpym See § and ¶ of my answer. There are actually multiple copies of them. The problem then is that it is low-level -- for example `xshift=10pt` causes the x-coordinate increased by `10pt`; and `rotate=10` will fuck everything up. There is no guarantee that it should work as expected.

Comment: I don't know the code (and I don't want to ;)), so I can't judge § and ¶. But I know that `(current subpath start)` in tikz works very well with all transforms, so in tikz level there is already a good candidate. But as you point out this should be done on PGF level ...

Comment: @Kpym nope, what I just pointed out is that it is in (the lower part of) PGF level. Even `(current subpath start)` is defined already in PGF level. (`pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex` line 1069.) I might be able to fix the problem in three days... but the point is that it is too low level, it is really really difficult to trace all registers.

Comment: If `(current subpath start)` is defined at PGF (very low) level why you create two new registers and do not use it ? In general the higher levels can use things from the lower one, no ?