# Relative coordinates after cycle with transform

Tags: tikz-pgf, coordinates, transformation

When I was trying to understand [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/282953) I discovered a strange behavior when we use relative coordinates just after `cycle` in a transformed path.

Here is an example (the black path) :

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[green]       (0,0) -- ++(1,0) -- ++(0,1) -- cycle node[red]{.} -- ++(0,1);
    \draw[xshift=15mm] (0,0) -- ++(1,0) -- ++(0,1) -- cycle node[red]{.} -- ++(0,1);
    \draw[green]     (3.5,0) -- ++(1,0) -- ++(0,1) -- cycle node[red]{.} -- ++(0,1);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If we replace `cycle` by `(current subpath start)` all three lines look the same.

**Question:** Is this behavior of `cycle` normal (documented), or is it a bug ?

**Edit:** For me `cycle` and `(current subpath start)` should not differ on how they move the current point, but only on how the path is "closed".
So in some sens tikz should add `--(current subpath start)` after any `cycle` (it already adds `(current subpath start)--` before `cycle` in some situations as explained in *14.2.1 Straight Lines*)

Comment: xshift is a persistent coordinate transform. See for example `\draw[xshift=15mm] (0,0) -- ++(1,0) -- ++(0,1) -- cycle \pgfextra{\pgfgetlastxy{\mya}{\myb}} node[below,red]{\mya\myb} -- ++(0,1);`. If you don't provide a location for the node it picks up the last known (possibly transformed coordinate)

Comment: @percusse ok, but why `cycle` doesn't "move" the current point to `(current subpath start)` ?

Comment: It does but the point gets transformed. The transforms are global

Comment: @percusse I understand what is happening, I think : the transformation is applied for the second time to the coordinate that is already transformed. But this looks like a bug for me. Is it ? In any case, bug or not, this behavior is non logical : the line in `--++(0,1)` is drawn from `(1.5,0)` and the coordinate `++(0,1)` is calculated from `(3,0)` ... I have already seen this "double transformation" in other situations.

Comment: `(current subpath start)` is a fixed and named reference. The transform doesn't apply to it because it is already on the canvas. But the node without a specific **explicit** location picks up whatever known to TikZ and the coordinate gets `\pgf@process`ed. It's not a double application but rather asking for `(0,0)` point and receiving `([xshift=15mm]0,0)`. Add `\pgfextra{\pgftransformreset}` in between the cycle and node and you should see it.

Comment: @percusse well, if you ask for `(0,0)` and you get `([xshift=15mm]0,0)` and then you apply `[xshift=15mm]` to this points, this is what I call "double transformation" ;)

Comment: No not like that. You ask for it and receive the transformed coordinates filled in to `\pgf@x` and `\pgf@y`. It's only applied once. I used that notation to explain myself.

Comment: @percusse by taking already transformed `\pgf@x` and `\pgf@y` and then apply the transform to this, is what I call "double transformation" ;)

Comment: I think I can't explain myself clearly. When you don't have a named reference all explicit coordinates are passed through the process. That actually makes it possible for the first part of the path such that you can use `++` syntax. Otherwise they would get drawn on top of the left picture. So it is a pretty convenient thing to have. If you want to have the node on the path use the timer with `[pos]` syntax or place it explicitly

Comment: @percusse In any case `cycle` should use the coordinates of `(current subpath start)` to set the current point OR should apply the inverse transform to `(\pgf@x,\pgf@y)`.

Comment: Then it will connect it to the left picture.

Comment: @percusse no ! replace the `cycle` by `(current subpath start)` on the black path and you will see (it is not connected to the left picture).

Comment: PDF closing is a PostScrip literal it is not kept by PGF.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in `tikz.code.tex` line 2846

> ```
> \def\tikz@@close cycle{%
>   \tikz@flush@moveto%
>   \edef\tikz@timer@start{\noexpand\pgfqpoint{\the\tikz@lastx}{\the\tikz@lasty}}
>   \tikz@make@last@position{\expandafter\pgfpoint\pgfsyssoftpath@lastmoveto}%
>   \tikz@path@close{\expandafter\pgfpoint\pgfsyssoftpath@lastmoveto}%
>   \def\pgfstrokehook{}%
>   \edef\tikz@timer@end{\noexpand\pgfqpoint{\the\tikz@lastx}{\the\tikz@lasty}}%
>   \let\tikz@timer=\tikz@timer@line%
>   \let\tikz@tangent\tikz@timer@start%
>   \tikz@scan@next@command%
> }
> ```

Where `\tikz@make@last@position{\expandafter\pgfpoint\pgfsyssoftpath@lastmoveto}` recalls the starting point of the current subpath. It is stored in absolute coordinate. Hence in your case, the three calls of `--cycle` involve PGF-points

```
\pgfpoint{0.0pt}{0.0pt}
\pgfpoint{42.67912pt}{0.0pt}
\pgfpoint{99.5846pt}{0.0pt}
```

And then when Ti*k*Z locates the nodes, these coordinates are used  **with** transformation... That is to say that the transformation, for example `xshift`, is applied **twice**! To see this very clearly, one might test

```
\tikz\draw(0,0)node[blue]{.}[xshift=1cm](0,0)[yshift=1cm]--(0,0)--cycle node[red]{.};
```

[image]

Now the red point is at `(2,1)` because the old `xshift` is applied twice and the young `yshift` is applied once.

To fix this, one needs to replace the coordinate by a "un-transformed" one. And you actually gave a hint: the node `(current subpath start)`. One might modify the definition as follows

```
\makeatletter
\def\tikz@@close cycle{%
  \tikz@flush@moveto%
  \edef\tikz@timer@start{\noexpand\pgfqpoint{\the\tikz@lastx}{\the\tikz@lasty}}
  %\tikz@make@last@position{\expandafter\pgfpoint\pgfsyssoftpath@lastmoveto}% replaced by the next line
  \tikz@make@last@position{\expandafter\pgfpointanchor{current subpath start}{center}}%
  \tikz@path@close{\expandafter\pgfpoint\pgfsyssoftpath@lastmoveto}%
  \def\pgfstrokehook{}%
  \edef\tikz@timer@end{\noexpand\pgfqpoint{\the\tikz@lastx}{\the\tikz@lasty}}%
  \let\tikz@timer=\tikz@timer@line%
  \let\tikz@tangent\tikz@timer@start%
  \tikz@scan@next@command%
}
```

Now it should work.

[image]

---

Full code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}

  \tikz\draw(0,0)node[blue]{.}[xshift=1cm](0,0)[yshift=1cm]--(0,0)--cycle node[red]{.};

\makeatletter
\def\tikz@@close cycle{%
  \tikz@flush@moveto%
  \edef\tikz@timer@start{\noexpand\pgfqpoint{\the\tikz@lastx}{\the\tikz@lasty}}
  %\tikz@make@last@position{\expandafter\pgfpoint\pgfsyssoftpath@lastmoveto}% replaced by the next line
  \tikz@make@last@position{\expandafter\pgfpointanchor{current subpath start}{center}}%
  \tikz@path@close{\expandafter\pgfpoint\pgfsyssoftpath@lastmoveto}%
  \def\pgfstrokehook{}%
  \edef\tikz@timer@end{\noexpand\pgfqpoint{\the\tikz@lastx}{\the\tikz@lasty}}%
  \let\tikz@timer=\tikz@timer@line%
  \let\tikz@tangent\tikz@timer@start%
  \tikz@scan@next@command%
}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[green]       (0,0) -- ++(1,0) -- ++(0,1) -- cycle node[red]{.} -- ++(0,1);
    \draw[xshift=15mm] (0,0) -- ++(1,0) -- ++(0,1) -- cycle node[red]{.} -- ++(0,1);
    \draw[green]     (3.5,0) -- ++(1,0) -- ++(0,1) -- cycle node[red]{.} -- ++(0,1);
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This looks very promising ! Thanks. The question is : is this modification backward compatible with all "standard situations". I suppose yes.

Comment: I can't still find where but I think this will break some stuff (in the decorations I suspect). I should check this if I have time. Very nice analysis.