# TikZ - Accessing the start of a path

Tags: tikz-pgf

I know I can access the end of a path in TikZ naming the coordinate as  with:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{svg.path}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [green] svg {M201.1,673.2c1.4-39.8,2-52.2,18.2-70.8c11.7-13.5,18.3-24.3-7.7-49.4
        c-39.3-38-43.2-59.2,1-90.2c18.1-12.7,67.1-20.2,25.4-36.6c-18.2-7.2-23.5-9.7-26.9-39.2c-3-26.7-17.7-28.2-37.7-35
        c-20-6.9-87.7-28.8-50.2-78.2c23.5-31,58.6-73.9,83.1-118.2c13.3-24,22.4-56.5,38.6-85.9} coordinate (End);
\fill [red] (End) circle (4pt);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

How can I access the start of the path in the same way?

Comment: This come to be a real problem when one uses `cycle`. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/282953/.

Answer (score 5):

That's a tricky one!  The `svg` syntax shortcuts much of the TikZ path construction mechanism so the obvious solution, `coordinate[pos=0] (Start)`, doesn't seem to work.

So this method gets the path once it's been constructed and strips off the initial coordinate.  Then it creates a TikZ coordinate at that point.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

%\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/364315/86}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{svg.path}

\makeatletter

\def\tikz@startcoord#1#2#3#4\pgf@stop#5{%
\begingroup
\pgftransformreset
  \pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{#2}{#3}}%
  \pgfnode{coordinate}{center}{}{#5}{}%
  \endgroup
  }

\tikzset{
  coordinate at start/.code={
    \tikz@addmode{%
      \pgfsyssoftpath@getcurrentpath\@temp
      \expandafter\tikz@startcoord\@temp\pgf@stop{#1}
    }%
  }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[xshift=1cm]
\draw [coordinate at start=Start,green,yshift=2cm] svg {M201.1,673.2c1.4-39.8,2-52.2,18.2-70.8c11.7-13.5,18.3-24.3-7.7-49.4
        c-39.3-38-43.2-59.2,1-90.2c18.1-12.7,67.1-20.2,25.4-36.6c-18.2-7.2-23.5-9.7-26.9-39.2c-3-26.7-17.7-28.2-37.7-35
        c-20-6.9-87.7-28.8-50.2-78.2c23.5-31,58.6-73.9,83.1-118.2c13.3-24,22.4-56.5,38.6-85.9} coordinate (End);
\end{scope}
\fill [red] (End) circle (4pt);
\fill [blue] (Start) circle (4pt);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document

}
```

There may be a simpler way to do this ...

---

Updated to ignore current coordinate transformation (otherwise they get applied twice).

Comment: Very nice indeed! But, would you be able to make it more sturdy? It fails if you include the \draw command in between \begin{scope}[yscale=-1,xscale=1]  and \end{scope}

Comment: it also fails if you add "xshift=25" to the \draw options. It would be nice to have a way to do it that can withstand the changes in the draw command. Would inverting the direction of the path (drawing it backwards) and then use the coordinate to get the end work?

Comment: @Knudsen The coordinate transformations were getting applied twice.  This version resets the coordinate matrix before defining the coordinate to avoid that.

Answer (score 3):

Probably a bit cruder than the OP requirements, but if splitting the svg path is tolerable then putting a coordinate after the first moveto can work:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{svg.path}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [green, xshift=25] 
  svg {M201.1,673.2} 
  coordinate (Start)
  svg {c1.4-39.8,2-52.2,18.2-70.8c11.7-13.5,18.3-24.3-7.7-49.4
       c-39.3-38-43.2-59.2,1-90.2c18.1-12.7,67.1-20.2,25.4-36.6
       c-18.2-7.2-23.5-9.7-26.9-39.2c-3-26.7-17.7-28.2-37.7-35
       c-20-6.9-87.7-28.8-50.2-78.2c23.5-31,58.6-73.9,83.1-118.2
       c13.3-24,22.4-56.5,38.6-85.9}
  coordinate (End);
\fill [blue] (Start) circle [radius=.1];
\fill [red] (End) circle [radius=.1];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```